# Convert teradata data with timezone and load to timestamp with time zone colum

Tags: date, timezone, teradata

I have a date data with time zone as below:

`eventTime: 2021-02-02T23:10:00Z`

and my teradata column data type is `TIMESTAMP(6)` with timezone.

I am not able to convert and load this data into the teradata table, so could you please anyone help me to resolve this.

Comment: Try `cast(eventTime as timestamp(0) format 'yyyy-mm-ddBhh:mi:ssB')`

Comment: Or convert the string to `'2021-02-02 23:10:00+00:00'` format.